# Yii2 Выборка из одной таблицы записей с повторяющимися значениями одного столбца

Tags: mysql, yii2

Как в Yii2 используя ActiveQuery сделать выборку из одной таблицы всех тех записей, у которых значения одного столбца равны друг другу (повторяются).